# Redirect the same URL's from old domain to new subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to automatically redirect all URL's under the "forum" directory of my old domain to the same URL's in my new subdomain.

For example, olddomain.com/forum/topic1 will redirect automatically to subdomain.com/forum/topic1

Likewise, olddomain.com/forum/childforum/topic1 will redirect to subdomain.com/forum/childforum/topic1

And contrastingly, olddomain.com/best-site-ever.html DOESN'T redirect anywhere because it's not under the forum directory.

The URL's will always be the same, but I want to do this only for those in the forum directory. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!